# How to make a div element responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am having container div element, which height is 100%. The **buttonGroup** div element is populated in jsp, it can contain multiple buttons, so it's height will **grow dynamically**.

after **buttonGroup** div element occupied certain height, **remaining height** should be assigned to **displayArea** div element. How to do this in css3 ? The design should be responsive.

```
<div id="container" style="height: 100%;">
      <div id="buttonGroup">
             <input id="testbtn" type="button" value="Test">
      </div>
      <div id="dislayArea">
          ------ data ------
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **display:table** property for this. Write like this:

```
#container{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid red;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
#buttonGroup{
    background:red;
    display:table-row;
    height:20%;
}
#dislayArea{
    background:green;
    display:table-row;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/DV2F5/

Answer (score 3):

You can use jQuery to achieve this.

Like:

```
var bgh = $(document).height() - $("#buttonGroup").prop('scrollHeight');
$("#displayArea").height(bgh);
```